# How do encrypt .Net Core AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: encryption, sass, huawei-mobile-services

I encountered encryption error when connecting huawei cloud SASS. I communicated with Huawei technical personnel at that time, but there was no encryption error. Sample code for Net Core

Comment: Your description is not clear, what is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.